# QMainWindow::keyReleaseEvent is not working as expected

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow, keyrelease

Here is my code:

.h file

```
class MyMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    ...
protected:
    virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    virtual void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
private:
    bool _altKeyDown;
    ...
}
```

the .cpp file

```
void MyMainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Alt) {
        _altKeyDown = true;
    }
}

void MyMainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if(getenv("DEBUG_MODE")) qDebug() << "keyReleaseEvent fired";
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Alt) {
        _altKeyDown = false;
    }
}
```

the `keyPressEvent` function is called every time I press a key, but when I release the key, the `keyReleaseEvent` is not called. Do I miss something?

Comment: Have you tried the debugger to make sure you are not entering this method?(Setting a break point at the first line of the function)

Comment: Do you have MainMenu in your form? It can affect the behavior.

Comment: @VahidNateghi I tried and it never entered the method.

Comment: @MM. I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: @MahmoudHassan: If you put a MainMenu in your form, the behavior of key `ALT` will be changed, it can not be captured.

Comment: @MM. Yes, I do have MainMenu in the form. so once I added MainMenu I can't use keyReleaseEvent ?

Comment: I encounter the same problem now, how was this one solved ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enable mouse event first, add `setMouseTracking(true);` in your construction function, like this:

```
MyMainWindow::MyMainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
}
```

Comment: How is mouse tracking related to this? anyway, I tried to add it but nothing changed.

Comment: sorry.I made a mistake.